# p-adic version of Liouville's approximation theorem

Tags: diophantine-approximation

Does anyone know of a p-adic analogue of Liouville's approximation theorem http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LiouvillesApproximationTheorem.html with proof?

I'm aware of Roth's theorem and subspace theorems which can be generalized to p-adic numbers, these are different in that the constants are not effective.

Comment: Anatoly: Is this the only paper on the subject? It looks like it's generalized over any extension field. 

Comment: I'm intereste in ways that ordinary Liouville's theorem relates to p-adic Liouville's theorem

Comment: So far I found only this one.

Answer (score 2):

See the paper by J.-H. Evertse, *Symmetric improvements on Liouville's inequality*: http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~evertse/99-sym.pdf (dead link), https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/crll.2000.2000.issue-527/crll.2000.085/crll.2000.085.xml (possibly a paywall).